# Не переходит по ссылкам из файла html

Tags: html, css, ссылки

Имеется вот такая проблема, есть файл works.html, из него я ставлю ссылку на файл details.html и при нажатии ЛКМ он не хочет переходить на страницу detais.html, но например из консоли или когда открываешь ссылку с помощью ПКМ (открыть в новой вкладке) всё прекрасно открывается, как фиксить? Нужно ли что-то подключать или дописывать?
[image: файлы находятся рядом с друг другом]
[image: скрин пути к файлу]

Answer (score 0):

как вариант сделать:
`<?php header('Location: detais.html'); ?>` 
при нажатии на ссылку
только нужно будет поменять works.html => works.php

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена, забыл убрать скрипт запрещающий пользователю лкм при открытом popup окне... Спасибо за внимание